# Update array with a search

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to modify the NSMutableArray `directoryList` in a table view to search results.
The table view updates correctly when searching.
But when accessing the files in `directoryList` by selecting a row the results are based on the un-searched `directoryList`.

This is how I fill the array:

```
- (void) myDirectoryLogFunction
{
    NSLog(@"This is the log");

    NSString *path1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Logs/"];
    NSString *path2 = @"/Library/Logs/";

    directoryList1 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path1 error:nil]
                           pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

    directoryList2 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path2 error:nil]
                           pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

    directoryList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList1];
    [directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList2];

    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < directoryList.count; i++)
    {                      
        [rows addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[directoryList objectAtIndex:i], @"Logs", nil]];
    }

    [_LogListController setContent:rows];
    [logsTableView reloadData];
}
```

This is my row selection method:

```
- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [logsTableView selectedRow];

    if (selectedRow <= directoryList1.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"row is: %lu", selectedRow);

        NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];

        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

        if (content != NULL)
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        } else
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:@"No permission to read log"];
        }
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"row is: %lu", selectedRow);

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];

        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];

        if (content != NULL)
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        } else
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:@"No permission to read log"];
        }
    }
}
```

This is my search method:

```
-(IBAction)controlTextDidEndEditing:(id)sender
{
    if ([[[self mySearchField] stringValue] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Logs contains[cd] Logs)"];
        [_LogListController setFilterPredicate: filter];
        // directoryList.count when testing remains on un-searched directoryList
        NSLog(@"directoryList.count is: %lu", directoryList.count);

    } else
    {
        NSString *_searchString = [[self mySearchField] stringValue];

        NSPredicate *_searchResults = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Logs contains[cd] %@)", _searchString];
        [_LogListController setFilterPredicate: _searchResults];
        NSLog(@"directoryList.count is: %lu", directoryList.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use the filtered array to get the correct path  you are still using the original array(directorylist1);

Comment: @Radu How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching (filtering) the source data then your selection code needs to work with that data source. So, using `if (selectedRow <= directoryList1.count)` won't work because the count of your original un-filtered data is wrong.

Instead, check for existence, not count:

```
if ([directoryList1 containsObject:selectedObject])
```

Where `selectedObject` is the object obtained from your filtered list for the selected row (looks like `[directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]`).

You need to keep clear between your filtered and non-filtered data and how it's being used. Also note that if the 2 arrays have files with the same name then you could run into issues...

---

You might want to consider just having one array, not 2. Put the full file paths into the array, then you don't beed to worry about duplicates. For display, use the `lastPathComponent` of the path.

Have another array which is either:

```
if (!isSearching) {
    dataSourceArray = directoryListArray;
} else {
    dataSourceArray = [directoryListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...];
}
```

This keeps the code a lot cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Wain I understand what you're saying, and that was also the idea I had, that directoryList1 and 2 need to get updated as well, but how. I replaced `if (selectedRow <= directoryList1.count)` with `if ([directoryList1 containsObject:[directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]])` but the problem persists.

Comment: I somehow need to get these directories either fused together, or split them up in the search method I suppose. I think the first one is the easiest, I wouldn't mind if the table showed only paths.

Comment: Are you actually filtering `directoryList `, it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks @Wain will implement the changes. And no I am not filtering, I tried that before, but the problem was not solved. I tried with `[directoryList filterUsingPredicate:filter];`

Comment: I still need some more code to get the array of paths, so far I only get the file name with `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath`

Comment: So you have the path, and the array of file names. Iterate and use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to join them together.

Comment: I iterate through it like this `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= directoryList1.count; i++)
    {
        filePaths1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }` But I get a warning incompatible pointer types NSMutableArray from NSString, how do I fix that?

Comment: You don't try to set an array pointer to a string... `[filePaths1 addObject:...];`

Comment: Thanks @Wain but now the `directoryList` is empty, I used: `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i <= directoryList2.count; i++)
    {
        [filePaths2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList2 objectAtIndex:i]]];
    } directoryList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [directoryList addObjectsFromArray:filePaths1];` We are getting really close to a solution however.

Comment: Did you log each of the arrays created during the processing? Add lots of logs at the moment so you can see in detail what the code is actually doing. Don't make assumptions.

Comment: Logging reveals `directoryList1` contains all the right items, `filePaths1` however contains no objects.

Comment: Did you create an `filePaths1` instance? Not that you need it - you can just put the results directly into `directoryList`.

Comment: I gave this a plus one for the learning effect (as you answered an earlier question about this), god how I wish there was a school with teacher's for Objective-C, but SO comes so close. And I already had created a comment line so I won't forget in future, my my, should have known, but this isn't such an easy issue I hope other's will learn just as much.

Comment: Thanks, bought, read almost almost all their books and did the challenges, their locations aren't in my country however, yet. Back to the problem, I changed everything, but now the problem is still appearing, I also used `NSArray *aux = [NSMutableArray array];
        [directoryList filterUsingPredicate:filter];
        aux = [directoryList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
        [directoryList removeAllObjects];
        directoryList = [aux mutableCopy];
        [logsTableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);`

Comment: Also how do I include your isSearching method, I am filling it once in a method, and in another search method I would have to fill it with NSPredicate.

Comment: `isSearching` would be used in a method where you pass the search string or something like that. It controls whether the data source array is a plain copy (no search required) or filtered (search text exists).

Comment: That's my method, `controlTextDidEndEditing` basically the third of my methods, which I am showing in the question. And I figure its just about the same as yours, but the problem that `directoryList` seems to be left untouched from the filtering.

Comment: I got a new take to tackle the problem, when inspected it using breakpoints, I saw that the last line `NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);` in the `controlTextDidEndEditing` was not even called, leading me to believe that there is a problem with `[directoryList filterUsingPredicate:filter];`.

Comment: That was just the fact that I had not created a separate xib-file for the class, but still the problem remains, I cannot display files  correctly from updated array of search results (as revealed by selecting the row).

Answer (score 0):

I Imagine you need something like this:

```
- (void) tableViewSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [logsTableView selectedRow];

    if (selectedRow <= directoryList1.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"row is: %lu", selectedRow);
        NSArray *filteredArray = [directoryList filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];

        NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [filteredArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];

        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

        if (content != NULL)
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        } else
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:@"No permission to read log"];
        }
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"row is: %lu", selectedRow);

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Library/Logs/%@", [directoryList objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];

        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:NULL];

        if (content != NULL)
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:content];
        } else
        {
            [logsScrollViewTextView setString:@"No permission to read log"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Radu for you answer, however `filter` would need to be defined locally I assume, in the `controlTextDidEndEditing`. Even after class-wide definition of `filter` I will have to assign the search field to a local action somehow afterwards. But this a nice new take on the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: I got a new take to tackle the problem, when inspected it using breakpoints, I saw that the last line `NSLog(@"%@", directoryList);` in the `controlTextDidEndEditing` was not even called, leading me to believe that there is a problem with `[directoryList filterUsingPredicate:filter];`.

Comment: I tried your method and declared the filter as ivar, now I get the error `predicate can not be nil`, which is the case when I start the programm. Then when I search for something I get `this class is not key value coding compliant`